# Red-haired woman bethrothed to silver-haired prince, they are in charge of an island?

Tags: story-identification, novel

I read this novel several times as a kid but I can't remember the name of it today. From what I can remember, here are some details:

- Probably an early 90s or late 80s fantasy novel.
- There was a matriarchal society, women ruled and princes were considered useless to be married off
- The two main characters were a silver-haired prince and he was to wed a red-haired woman.
- I believe her name was something like "megarea" or "megaria" but I could be wrong. The prince's name is less clear to me, but "crispen" or something that starts with a c sounds about right.
- The woman hated the man and resented having to marry him. She saw men as weaklings, and often called him 'best-bethrothed' or something like that in a spiteful way. Only at the end of the novel did she come to tolerate him more.
- They were put in charge of running an island, and had to survive there. Most of the novel, or at least the latter half, took place on that island. There were lots of details about how they improved its infrastructure, had better methods of growing food, etc.
- There was a scene where they travelled to that island and there was a storm and a mage protected the ship during the storm.
- The name might have had 'sunset' or some similar word in it.

That's about all I can remember, sorry. I did like it and read it at least twice, but I can't remember its name at all. Thanks for any help anyone can give!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe you are referring to "The Towers of the Sunset" Book 2 of the Recluce series by L.E. Modesitt. The main character would be Creslin, the red haired lady would be Megaera. The island they go to would be Recluce.

Comment: thanks! yes it seems to be "The Towers of Sunset", which was the second book in the series. i had no idea there were other books in that series and thought it was a stand-alone book.

Comment: There are a lot of them. Read them All. You will not be disappointed.

Comment: i am thinking of doing that yes. any thoughts on whether i should read the novels in the order they were written or chronologically according to their timeline?

Comment: How to answer.....it's taken a bit of thought. I read them as they came out and I remember the enjoyment i got from relating a reference to the past when reading about the event as part of the main narrative in the later books. But that also happens when you are reminded of the previous book when reading the one later in the timeline. This series is rare - It's not many authors who can produce a universe that is so consistent either way works well. On balance, i'd probably go for reading them in timeline order but then.....he's not finished writing the series yet....

Answer (score 5):

Without question this is *Towers of the Sunset*, it was the second Recluce novel I read (after *The Magic of Recluce*).

I think that the author recommends reading the series in order of publication at least from the link given [here](http://www.travelinlibrarian.info/recluce/recluce/chronology.html).  Personally the Lorn books (*Magi of Cyador*/*Scion of Cyador*) are my favourites after having read nearly the entire series.  I enjoyed these the most and I re-read them regularly, but all of the novels are good.